# discord.py using JSON in cogs?

Tags: python, json, discord.py

I've been working on a Discord bot lately and all my commands are in a single py file. I am currently trying to implement cogs to my bot since my plan is to make it run 24/7 and public, so if something fails I can just easily fix it without shutting down the entire bot (and also to make the script itself more cleaner and organized). I am relatively new to using JSON and cogs, so any help would be much appreciated.

**Note 1:** I don't want to pass the absolute path for it since I'll be hosting this bot on a VPS.
**Note 2:** My `reports.json` file is in the `\cogs` folder, not in `\CogTest` folder.

Trying to run it raises this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\test\CogTest\cogs\warns.py", line 14, in <module>
    class Warns(commands.Cog):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\test\CogTest\cogs\warns.py", line 20, in Warns
    with open('reports.json', encoding='utf-8') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'reports.json'
```

Here's my example warn class:

```
# Imports

import discord
import random
import asyncio
import json
import datetime
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Permissions
from discord import Intents
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions
from discord.ext.commands import MissingPermissions
from discord.ext.commands import BucketType

# Class 

class Warns(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

# Bot is online

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('test running')

# Warn Command

    with open('reports.json', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        try:
            report = json.load(f)
        except ValueError:
            report = {}
            report ['users'] = []


    @commands.command(pass_context=True)
    @commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
    async def warn(self, ctx, user:discord.User,*reason:str):
        author = ctx.author
        if user == ctx.author:
            await ctx.send(f"{ctx.message.author.mention}, you can't warn yourself!", delete_after=10.0)
            return
        if not reason:
            await ctx.send(f'{ctx.message.author.mention}, please provide a reason for warning!', delete_after=10.0)
            return
        reason = ' '.join(reason)
        await ctx.send(f'{user.mention} has been warned by **{author.name}**. Reason: ``{reason}``')
        await user.send(f'You have been warned in **{ctx.guild.name}** by **{author.name}**. Reason: ``{reason}``')
        for current_user in report['users']:
            if current_user['name'] == user.name:
                current_user['reasons'].append(reason)
                break
        else:
            report['users'].append({
            'name':user.name,
            'reasons': [reason,]
            })
        with open('reports.json', 'w+') as f:
            json.dump(report,f)

# Warn Error 

    @warn.error
    async def warn_error(self, ctx, error):
        if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
            await ctx.send(f"{ctx.message.author.mention}, you don't seem to have the permission to run this command!", delete_after=10.0)
        if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
            await ctx.send(f"{ctx.message.author.mention}, please provide the member's username that you want to warn!", delete_after=10.0)
        if isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
            await ctx.send(f"{ctx.message.author.mention}, I couldn't find that member. Are you sure you provided the correct member?", delete_after=10.0)


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Warns(client))
```

Here's the main load / unload code, you can check if there's anything wrong with it if you wish

```
# Imports 

import discord
import random
import asyncio
import json
import datetime
import os
from discord import Permissions
from discord import Intents
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions
from discord.ext.commands import MissingPermissions
from discord.ext.commands import BucketType
from os import listdir


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "y!")

# Load / Unload

@client.command()
async def load(ctx, extension):
    client.load_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')

@client.command()
async def unload(ctx, extension):
    client.unload_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')

for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')

client.run('token here')
```

Comment: Python file paths in `open` are relative to the current working directory, not the Python source directory. Try `open('cogs/reports.json')`

Comment: The file path error seems to have worked, but now it doesn't write the warns in the `reports.json` for some reason. I also added a command where you can check your warns, yet nothing, it's not functional without raising any errors since the warn command itself doesn't write the warns, hence the checkwarns command can't read it